# File chooser does not show the hard drive contents?

Tags: java, applet, jpanel, jfilechooser

I am creating a file chooser in Java using `JFileChooser` as shown in the code below. I am creating the file chooser from inside the `init()` function. When I run the GUI the file chooser appears but there are no directories or hard drive appears so I can choose my file.

What am I doing wrong?

### Code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getSource() == Bsearch){
            System.out.println("Button Search Pressed");
             JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();// JFileChooser-Objekt for Bsearch-Button
              chooser.showDialog(null, "Search File");// Dialog zum Öffnen von Dateien anzeigen  
              Tdatei.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());//set File in Textfield Tdate
    }//if
}
```

### Errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.paho.sample.GuiAsApplet$1.actionPerformed(GuiAsApplet.java:261)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be that it fails because it does not have a context. Try passing `this` instead of `null` when opening the dialog.

Comment: i tried it, eclipse saied it is not applicable

Comment: show us the line 261 of GuiAsApplet.java

Comment: @pietv8x according to the docs: If the parent is null, then the dialog depends on no visible window, and it's placed in a look-and-feel-dependent position such as the center of the screen.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. ..

Comment: 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 4) Is the applet code digitally signed?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selection mode of your filechooser.

`chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);`

[Oracle File Chooser tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)